# Javascript function .toString() in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my webpack developing case, I need to output function as strings by `function.toString()`. But webpack may translate some statements into module styles.

```
const myFunc = function{
  this.methods.log(Date.now())
}

myFunc.toString()
```

```
"myFunc(){this.methods.log(_Users_xxx_Desktop_designer_web_node_modules_babel_runtime_corejs2_core_js_date_now__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default()());}"
```

What I need:

```
"myFunc(){this.methods.log(Date.now())}"
```

I handled `this` pointer to correct object. I just want webkit to ignore this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case the transformation is done first by babel, cus you use `transform-runtime` plugin, it decides that the `Date` API needs to come from `core-js`. Webpack steps in later because it sees `Date` now refer to a imported lib, so it transform the import statement to `WEBPACK_IMPORT_MODULE`.

You either tune babel to disallow it transform `Date`, or you can do the reverse. You write a string of function, then eval it to get a real function.

```
const myFuncStr = `function (){
  this.methods.log(Date.now())
}`

const myFunc = eval(myFuncStr)
```

Comment: The content of stringed function is open to users so I can't know which objects will be used. And I want to work with TypeScript and editor heigh-light, use string and eval it is not a good practice for me. Are there some comment commands or other things to tell Babel `skip this function`?

Comment: @leili AFAIK, no such bail out

Comment: One thing I can think of is use babel polyfill istead of transform runtime. Beside, I don't think it's bad practice. All things come at their price. Just do whatever solves the problem.